# Python C/API assign a C++ variable

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I am writing a small program with the Python C/API, which basically calls a simple Python script. Here's the code:

```
#include <Python.h>

PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;

int main() {

    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyString_FromString("simplemodule");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "simplefunction");

    if(PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {

        PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);


    } else {

        PyErr_Print();

    }

    Py_DECREF(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Now, here is the code for *simplemodule.py*:

```
def simplefunction():
    m = 5*5
    return m
```

My question is: How can I assign the variable *m* to a C++ variable, so I can use it in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`PyInt_AsLong`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html?highlight=pyint_as_long#PyInt_AsLong) to convert the return value to C long.

```
...
if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
    PyObject *res = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
    if (res != NULL) {
        long n = PyInt_AsLong(res); // <---------
        cout << n << endl;
    } else {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. And if the module function returns a string, should I use something like `PyString_AsString`?

Comment: @jndok, Yes, use [`PyString_AsString`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html#PyString_AsString). BTW, it returns `char *`, not C++ `string`.